# linking one dictionary to another in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a dictionary that is of the form:

```
d[class name]=(list of files)
```

ex:

```
d[earn]=(6,7,4)
```

where 6.txt,7.txt and 4.txt are the files belonging to the class "earn"

Now, I need to create another dictionary d2 such that:

```
d2[earn]=(12,3,2,17)
```

where

- 12 is the number of times the word "earn" occurs in 6.txt,
- 3 is the number of times the word "earn" occurs in 7.txt,
- 4 is the number of times the word "earn" occurs in 4.txt
- 17 is the number of times the word "earn" occurs in all the three files,i.e; the sum.

Here is my code:

```
import collections
import sys
import os
import re
sys.stdout=open('dictionary.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob


folderpath='d:/individual-articles'
counter=Counter()

with open('topics.txt') as f:
    d= collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        value, *keys = line.strip().split('~')
        for key in filter(None, keys):
            d[key].append(value+".txt")

filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

def words_generator(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word
word_count_dict = {}
for file in filepaths:
    f = open(file,"r")
    words = words_generator(f)
    for word in words:
        if word not in word_count_dict:
              word_count_dict[word] = {"total":0}
        if file not in word_count_dict[word]:
              word_count_dict[word][file] = 0
        word_count_dict[word][file] += 1              
        word_count_dict[word]["total"] += 1        
for k in word_count_dict.keys():
    for filename in word_count_dict[k]:
        if filename == 'total': continue
        counter.update(filename)

for word, counts in word_count_dict.items():
    print(word, counts['total'])
```

I need to print d2, but my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you're looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d2 = defaultdict(list)
for word,files in d.items():
    for fname in files: #go over each file name in the 'list' which was associated with the key 'word' in d
        with open(fname) as f: 
            d2[word].append(f.read().count(word)) #add the count of the word in the file
           #d2[word].append(f.read().split().count(word)) use this if you want words not occurances of 'word' in the file
    d2[word].append(sum(d2[word])) #add the sum of all the counts
print d2
```

Comment: Note that `f.read().count(word)` can have unexpected results as: `"foobar".count('foo')-->1`, prefer `regex`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yeah I realised that after posting, added a `f.read().split().count(word)` way beneath it. Using a regex there could be better, the OP can look into that.

Comment: i get this eror: File "C:\Python33\access_dict.py", line 36, in <module>
    with open(fname) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '16951'

Comment: @radhika you might need to go `+'.txt'` if the *full* file name isn't included in the list of file names.

Comment: @HennyH: you mean with open(fname+'.txt') as f: ??